# Get запрос код страницы

Tags: javascript, get

Подскажите как правильно сделать Гет запрос на чистом JS чтобы получить код страницы?
вот

```
$(document).ready(function() {
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.youtube.com/channel/HmkfnMNyam79EQ/videos", true);
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4)
    {

        if (xhr.responseText)
        {
            var data = xhr.responseText;
```

такой код почему то не работает может как то можно проще?
Хочу сделать плагин для Хрома`

Comment: Кросс доменные запросы?)

Comment: да,не могу получить код страницы в переменную

Comment: Намёк не понят... пробуем проще https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain